# Como imprimir documento generado por página web con vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, impresion

un saludo a todos. A ver si alguien me puede ayudar con lo siguiente: tengo una macro en excel con la cual realizo web scraping y me funciona perfectamente. la página web tiene la opción de una impresora para generar un certificado en PDF. Al darle click genera el PDF y solicita la ruta para guardar. La idea es que la macro pueda generar el certificado y me lo guarde en una ruta automáticamente. Hasta el momento he logrado hacerle click y me sale la ventana emergente de impresion de windows. No se de ahí en adelante.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero es esto:
1: hacer click y cuando me salga la ventana emergente de impresion hacerle click también y se me genere el PDF de inmediato y lo guarde en una ruta específica.

Gracias por la atención

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Dato importante: Esa ventana de impresión que abres la gestiona el OS, no el navegador ni el sitio web. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo en colocar el código; creo que con la explicacion es suficiente, debido a que el codigo precisamente es lo que quiero conseguir.

Comment: Si realmente estás haciendo Webscraping con VBA, pues para que puedas recibir ayuda necesitas mostrar tus avances ya que obviamente hay muchas formas de hacer eso.

Comment: No es la mejor opción pero podrías probar con SEndKeys. Si no, mira en Google tambien sobre urldownloadtofile pero es bastante lioso. Yo optaría por el SendKeys por comodidad.

Comment: Ok amigo, parece que me ha funcionado con SendKeys, gracias por tu ayuda, muy amable